# Error on assets:precompile because of ckeditor assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ckeditor

I have a problem when having a `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` because of CKEditor Gem issue.

My error is this:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "..._footer{filter:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "}"
  (in /home/test_test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2@test_test/gems/ckeditor-4.0.11/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/override.js.erb)
(sass):6
```

Can somebody help me. I can't deploy my app. I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/252), which has been fixed at least twice :-P.

You can fix it yourself by editing `/home/test_test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2@test_test/gems/ckeditor-4.0.11/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/dialog_iequirks.css`.

Look at the end of the file, and make sure it does not end with `cke_dialog_footer{filter:}`. Here is the [fix in github](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/commit/3d6c82a878b87c548cfd8537bd85d33fe5c52bd0)

Comment: Hi Uri Agassi. Thanks for answering my questions. Right now my error is still the same. I already did that by it is still the same. Sorry I'm a beginner in rails.

Comment: I already did what have you said. But I still get the same error. This class is cke_dialog_footer{filter:""} in the gem, but when I changed it to cke_dialog_footer{filter: none} but it didn't work.

Comment: You still have the exact same error? try to find any other asset within the gem which contains `_footer{filter:}`

Comment: I did the same too. But I'm still confused, the author of the gem updated the file dialog_iequirks.css but in when I run bundle install the old version of that file in the folder again. :(

Comment: @UriAgassi is there a version where we can pull the fix instead of modifying the gem?

Comment: @steamboy - I'm not sure, since it has been fixed a few times, and _should have been_ ok. I guess you should approach the author, and make sure that the fix is now in place.

Comment: @UriAgassi alright. It's weird it is still not working but thanks still.